# Maven extra sources wildcards

Tags: java, maven, build-helper-maven-plugin

I'm adding some extra sources to my Maven project and until now all is working well. I just want to make the extra source selection a little more more generic, because today I have something like:

```xml
<source>client/plugins/plug1/classes</source>
<source>client/plugins/plug2/classes</source>
<source>client/plugins/plug3/classes</source>
<source>client/plugins/plug4/classes</source>
<source>client/plugins/plug5/classes</source>
...
```

And I want to do it in this way:

```xml
<source>client/plugins/**/classes</source>
```

That's because some developers do not have all the plugins under their working space, and I don't want to modify my `pom.xml` in each dev environment.

Unfortunately that pattern doesn't work *-at least in Eclipse-* because the folders are not marked as **source**. I made a little research and I saw that Maven uses the [Ant patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) but it is not working.

Could you please tell me if it is possible to use that convention in `<sources>` definition?

Comment: It may be smarter to divide the project in sub modules, if not all developers have every part of the source, you get builds that change per developer

Comment: Sorry: Yes! I'm using it. I'm considering to create modules. It could be the solution, as @Ferrybig said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The [`sources`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html#sources) attribute of the `build-helper-maven-plugin:add-source` goal is a `File` array, which means that every source must be a `File`, hence you can't use an Ant path pattern. The plugin will literally add the file `client/plugins/**/classes` as a source directory (and since it doesn't exist, nothing will happen). This is the logs that I had when I tested it:

```
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-source (add-source) @ test ---
[INFO] Source directory: <omitted>\client\plugins\**\classes added.
```

But there's the matter of why you would want such a thing. It isn't clear from your question where are those "plugins" coming from but you shouldn't be in that situation. Each plugin should probably be a separate module of a [multi-module Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). This way, each plugin will handle its build and you can add a dependency on those modules.